# Delivering an xcode framework with other dependencies

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

We are trying to release an iOS version of our library and are planning on delivering it as a compiled static framework. Using Xcode the framework and test app we have are compiling successfully and running fine.

The question is: What is the best way to deliver it?

Our library is dependent on some other opensource frameworks, and we also want to ship a test app with the framework to show how to actually use the library properly.

Should we use an umbrella framework? Apple suggests "Don't Create Umbrella Frameworks" (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html)

Should we just deliver a zip that has our framework as well as all the frameworks we're dependent on and just tell the clients that they have to include those frameworks in their projects?

What's the best way to include the test app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Coming in 11 years late, did you get answer to Why we need to add 3rd party dependencies to client apps explicitly? If those dependencies are static, shouldn't they be automatically linked to your framework's binary and you don't have to ship them explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include the required frameworks with your compiled framework with the exception of frameworks that come standard with the iOS SDK. Most every framework is going to rely on Foundation and UIKit, those are frameworks that will most likely already be included. Anything else they won't have access to, include with your framework you send over.

Comment: What do you mean include them with our compiled framework? Just zip all the frameworks up together, or actually embed them as sub-frameworks in some-or-other approach?

Comment: My experience is that frameworks are bundled static libraries that have all the headers included. You can link your dependencies in the libraries. I don't think you would need to include Framework,UIKit in your zip as it would just make things confusing and messy on the other end. Those are already included and they would already have those. Test out your framework on a new project locally, make sure everything works, then just zip your framework and ship it.

Comment: We have dependencies on other 3rd party libraries like boost. Things that are already included, I wouldn't link in, but since everything is linked statically for ios, we have to have some method of shipping the boost framework with our framework.

Comment: I believe those will get bundled with your static library if properly linked. Our frameworks include several homegrown static libs. If properly linked, you should only need to ship the framework.

Comment: We have several static libs which are all bundled into the framework fine. The problem is that we need to compile the test app against both our framework and the frameworks that it is dependent on, since those are not bundled into the framework. We could theoretically link the entire dependent framework into our library, but then I think we force our customers to use our version of boost even if they don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CocoaPods as a means to manage the dependencies (especially if those dependencies are open-source).

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this more. From what I can tell, it looks like it would be useful in-house, but not if we're trying to deliver a standalone framework which includes other frameworks it's dependent on. (They are all opensource though, so I'll definitely give this a close look.)

Comment: I don't know what your framework does or what kind of customers you have, but I would not want to use a framework/library that was dependent upon other things that I could not update independently.  It's too easy to get into a situation where I use library A that depends on some set of things and library B that is dependent on incompatible versions of those things, and then I can't link everything together.

Comment: Right, so on windows we were able to ship with a dll and just compile everything together, so there were no dependencies, but on iOS you can't use dynamic libraries so we have to provide static frameworks for everything that we're using under the cover so they can all be linked together by the end user.